# Getting iframe content causes TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object

Tags: jquery, iframe

The function below is intended to grab/process the HTML of either a jQuery selector or a URL. If a URL is passed in, it generates an iframe and, after the iframe is loaded, grabs the iframe's HTML. (*Note: I'm not using external URLs, just other pages on the same site.*)

The function is throwing `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'myHTML.find')` whenever I pass in a URL. I don't understand why. Does anything stand out here?

```
1   mynamespace.html: function ( source ) {
2   // Grabs and processes the HTML of a jQuery selector or URL.
3      
4      var myHTML;
5
6         if ( $(source).is('iframe') ) {
7            // if it's an iframe, use .contents() 
8            myHTML = $(source).contents().find('html').clone();
9
10        } else if (source.indexOf('http://') === 0 ) {
11           // if it's a URL, load an iframe
12           $(document.body).append('<iframe id="printiframe" src="'+source+'"></iframe>');   
13           $('#printiframe').load(function() {
14               // once loaded, send it back into this function,
15               // where it can then be processed as an iframe
16               return mynamespace.html ('#printiframe');
17           });
18
19        } else {
20           myHTML = $(source).clone();
21        }   
22      
23        // Do stuff to the HTML here, such as myHTML.find('bla')...
24
25        return myHTML.html();
26   }
```

Comment: Do your page and the iframe sit in same domain?

Comment: Yes, the iframe src and everything else are on my single domain.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit, but I put in line numbers so that answers can refer to parts of your code easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you don't mind, but I edited your question to add line numbers to the code for ease of reference rather than repeating all of the code here.

Anyway, I believe the problem is with the `else if` branch starting on line 10. The sequence of execution will be:

- Line 12 - append the iframe
- Line 13 - make the ajax `.load()` request
- Lines 18/19 - the end of the branch
- Lines 22-24 - where you have your comment about doing stuff, at which point `myHTML` has not been assigned a value (hence the error you are getting)
- Line 25 - return from the function

Then, after the *asynchronous* Ajax request returns:

- Line 16 - the body of the callback function you provided.

This is the way asynchronous code works - no matter how fast the request, the callback won't be called until after the other code is finished executing. The `return` statement on line 16 doesn't return from your `mynamespace.html()` function, it returns from that callback (and nothing is paying attention to that return).

You could try to restructure your code slightly to use a *synchronous* ajax request, in which case execution would pause at line 13 until the response comes back, but that provides a poor experience for the user because the browser will be unresponsive in the mean time.

Better to restructure to stick with standard *aysnc* Ajax, and allow for the order of execution I described above. Without knowing how your `mynamespace.html()` is called I'm not sure I can advise on that.

<s>I believe you've run aground on the ["Same Origin Policy"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), also sometimes called the "Cross-Domain Security Policy" or other variations on that theme.</s>

You don't say what types of URL you are entering, but in a general sense JavaScript running in one frame can't access the content of another frame if the source is from a different domain.

(There are some workarounds to get cross-domain frames to communicate with each other, but only if both are cooperating - which wouldn't be the case here.)

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of those issues—I'm actually just using a single domain, the same domain as the script is on.

Comment: Thank you, this is really informative. The function is just called on a click event. How could I restructure to account for the order of execution? I guess one way would be to separate the HTML "getting" from the HTML processing- like my.HTMLget() and my.HTMLprocess() and make my.HTMLprocess() the callback function in the iframe .load() call.

Comment: That's just a naive guess--I'm thankful for any suggestions or recommended patterns.

Comment: Does the click event that calls `mynamespace.html()` do anything with the return value? If not there's an easy fix: keep your processing at line 23 where the "do stuff" comment is and insert a `return;` statement at line 18 (just after the `$.load()` statement). That will mean that when execution goes down that path it will make the Ajax statement and then stop, but then the ajax callback will call `mynamespace.html()` again and that time through it won't take that path again so it will get to your line 23 processing. (Or something like you suggested should work.)